# Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "SELECT"

Tags: sql, sql-server

ребят, выручайте - с SQL не работал - возникла ошибка запроса "SELECT" не могу решить никак.

```html
USE [TestDB]
GO

--CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PasswordTest](
--    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
--    [Name] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
--    [Password] [varbinary](150) NOT NULL
--) ON [PRIMARY]
--GO
 
--Insert into [PasswordTest] values (1, 'sql_shack_User1', HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'Sanya'))
--Insert into [PasswordTest] values (2, 'sql_shack_User2', HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'Luna'))
--GO

CREATE or alter FUNCTION GetUserByPasswordCompare (@password VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT *
    FROM
        [PasswordTest]
    WHERE
        [Password] = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @password);

SELECT [dbo].[GetUserByPasswordCompare]('Luna')
```

Текст ошибки:
**сообщение: 156, уровень: 15, состояние: 1, процедура: GetUserByPasswordCompare, строка: 23 [строка начала пакета: 2]
Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "SELECT".**

Comment: Замените строковый комментарий `--` на многострочный `/* */`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените вызов функции (последняя строка) на

```
SELECT * from [dbo].[GetUserByPasswordCompare]('Luna')
```

И не выполняйте её в одном пакете с созданием функции.